# How can I use autoform to populate a select element with #each?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Here is part of my form that I'd like to convert to using autoform.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<label for="pay_with" id="pay_with_label">Pay With</label>
<select name="pay_with" id="pay_with" class="form-control select select-primary mbl" required data-placeholder="Select an Option">
    <option value="Card">New Card</option>
    <option value="Check">New Bank</option>
    {{#each device}}
        <option value="{{card_id}}" selected {{selected}}>{{brand}} - {{last4}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

In autoform, how do I translate this part?

```
{{#each device}}
    <option value="{{card_id}}" selected {{selected}}>{{brand}} - {{last4}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a template helper function that returns the options array for your select menu, by mapping your devices array and adding in the extra options in order to get the proper schema for autoform, like so:

```
Template.myForm.helpers({
   deviceOptions: function() {

      var deviceOpts = devices.map(function(device) {
         return { label: device.brand+' - '+device.last4, value: device.card_id }
      });

      deviceOpts.unshift({ label: 'New bank', value: 'Check' });
      deviceOpts.unshift({ label: 'New card', value: 'Card' });

      return deviceOpts;
   },
});
```

Then, you can call the helper in your template directive:

```
{{> afFieldInput name="payWith" type="select" options=deviceOptions }}
```